# Twig for loop, how do I display the last element?

Tags: symfony, twig

Here's my code.

```
<th>Attachment</th>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        {% for attachment in lineup.attachments %}
                        <li><a href='http://files.example.com/{{ attachment.file_url }}'>{{ attachment.name }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </td>
```

This is posting EVERY attachment which is great but I just want it to post the last attachment it finds while iterating through the attachments table. For instance if it finds 10 attachments, I don't want all of them, just the 10th one. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of version 1.12.2 Twig contains a "last" filter
The syntax is like this:

```
{{ array|last }}
```

In your situation it would be:

```
{{ lineup.attachments|last }}
```

You can use it like:

```
{% set attachement = lineup.attachments|last %}
<li>
    <a href='http://files.example.com/{{ attachment.file_url }}'>
       {{ attachment.name }}
    </a>
</li>
```

You can read all about it here: [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html)

Comment: Thats the one I tried using but nothing gets displayed when I use it in the {% for %} statement where you suggested. When I use it in {{ attachment.name|last }} it just displays the last letter but still posts all 4 items @Robin Hermans

Comment: Dont use it in the for loop. You should use it like an object. See my last edit.

Comment: No problem. Success on your project.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to the accepted answer, there is no need to set it as a variable.  This works too:

```
<a href='http://files.example.com/{{ lineup.attachments|last.file_url }}'>
  {{ lineup.attachments|last.name }}
</a>
```